# compare in a Bash 2 files

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash

I am looking to compare in a Bash(linux) script 2 files (file1 and file2) containing indexes.
I'm looking to compare only the contents inside square bracket[]. In order to check if these contents are identical between file1 and file2.

Each file looks like this:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=%24external&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
MongoDB server version: 4.4.9
Database: dataexmple -- counters: [{"v":2,"key":{"_id":1},"name":"_id_"}]
Database: dataexmple -- diagexmple_contractor: [{"v":2,"key":{"_id":1},"name":"_id_"}]
Database: dataexmple -- diagexmple_contractor_histo: [{"v":2,"key":{"_id":1},"name":"_id_"}]
Database: dataexmple -- diagexmple_correspondence: [{"v":2,"key":{"_id":1},"name":"_id_"}]
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Is the data inside `[]` always the same for a given file?

Comment: Can the part between `[]` also contain brackets, i.e. can brackets be nested? Please post also your own attempt to solve the problem, and describe at which point you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, no the data is not always the memories for a data file.

Comment: I need to start the comparisons after the ´- -´ characters for each line.
No, there cannot be nested brackets.

The idea is to check if the indexes of file1 are identical to those of file2.
The output should for example show missing indexes in file 2.
If the indexes are the same, then it should print: all indexes are present.

I haven't started the resolution yet because I don't see how to do it.